# how to find the source of the table in kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have tables that are getting continuously ingested. I need to find the source of those tables from where those tables are getting ingested in Kusto. I don't know how to identify this. Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Manoranjini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.show commands 
| where CommandType == "DataIngestPull"
```

If the data URL was not masked, you should be able to see something like this:

| Text |
| --- |
| .ingest-from-storage into mytable<| @'https://mycluster.blob.core.windows.net/mypath/myfile.csv?''******' |

Comment: You're welcome. If that indeed answered your question, make sure to accept the answer (mark the V sign left to the answer)